# How to write conditional statements in R not limited to print() function?

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have a data frame of patient characteristics as follows:

[image]

I want to write a conditional statement to return the corresponding survival of patients aged 50-60, 60-70 and >70. How can I write such conditional statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example your data.frame is such:

```
set.seed(111)
df = data.frame(Gender=sample(1:2,100,replace=TRUE),
Age=sample(50:80,100,replace=TRUE),
target.TAA=sample(letters[1:5],100,replace=TRUE),
Surivial=rnbinom(100,mu=10,size=1))
```

We define the age groups:

```
df$ageGrp = cut(df$Age,breaks=c(50,60,70,+Inf),
labels=c("50-60","60-70",">70"),include.lowest=TRUE,right=FALSE)
```

To get survival do:

```
50-60 60-70   >70 
    9     5     5
```

You can also do it in dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(ageGrp=case_when(
       Age >= 50 & Age < 60 ~ "50-60",
       Age >= 60 & Age < 70 ~ "60-70",
       Age >= 70 ~ ">70"
     ))
   Gender Age target.TAA Surivial ageGrp
1        2  70          c        9    >70
2        1  68          b        6  60-70
3        2  50          a        1  50-60
4        1  74          c        0    >70
5        1  76          c        1    >70
6        1  77          d        0    >70
```

From the above you can group by the group and calculate for example Survival:

```
df %>% mutate(ageGrp=case_when(
       Age >= 50 & Age < 60 ~ "50-60",
       Age >= 60 & Age < 70 ~ "60-70",
       Age >= 70 ~ ">70"
     )) %>% group_by(ageGrp) %>%
summarize(Surivial=median(Surivial))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  ageGrp Surivial
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 >70           5
2 50-60         9
3 60-70         5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `cut2` from `Hmisc` (or `cut` from base R, if you prefer):

```
Hmisc::cut2(dt$age, cuts = seq(50, 70, 10))

## base R solution:
cut(df$Age, breaks = c(min(df$Age), seq(50, 70, 10), max(df$Age)), lowest = TRUE, right = FALSE)
```

**Edit:** 
Upon request, here is an alternative solution with conditional statements (sets to NA all values below or equal 50 in this case):

```
df$age <- ifelse(df$Age <= 60 & df$Age > 50, "50-60", 
                  ifelse(df$Age <= 70 & df$Age > 60, "60-70", 
                         ifelse(df$Age > 70, ">70", NA)))
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to write it with conditional statements?

Answer (score 0):

In `base R` (No packages required)

```
SurvivalByAge <- lapply(c("50:59","60:69","70:200"), function(X) df$Survival[unlist(lapply(eval(parse(text=X)),grep,df$Age))])
names(SurvivalByAge) <- c("50:59","60:69","70:200")
SurvivalByAge

$`50:59`
[1] 14  0  0  6

$`60:69`
[1] 5 3 5 5 7 7 4 7 9

$`70:200`
[1] 12  2 13  6  0
```

Or alternatively to get a sum

```
SurvivalByAge <- lapply(c("50:59","60:69","70:200"), function(X) sum(df$Survival[unlist(lapply(eval(parse(text=X)),grep,df$Age))]))
names(SurvivalByAge) <- c("50:59","60:69","70:200")
SurvivalByAge

$`50:59`
[1] 20

$`60:69`
[1] 52

$`70:200`
[1] 33
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(Age = c(59,63,71,67,48,78,65,65,73,78,56,67,69,43,58,61,60,75,66,56),Survival=c(6,5,12,4,10,6,5,7,2,0,14,7,9,6,0,3,5,13,7,0))
```